# java.lang.ClassFormatError

Tags: java, linux, classformaterror

I need to develop a sample Application and deploy it in Linux and test it .

The problem is that I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: com.tata.topSamples.QuoteData (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

By googling I found out that , You compiled the jar with a newer version of Java than the one on your Linux machine

**In my windows Environment I have 1.6 version and in Linux Environment the java version is of 1.4.2.**

How can we resolve this error?

Comment: Upgrade the Java installed on your Linux box? Or isn't that possible for you?

Comment: Update your Linux environment to a newer Java version; 1.4.2 is absurdly outdated.

Answer (score 4):

> Please tell me how can we resolve this error ??

Either compile with `-target 1.4` and `-source 1.4` flags, or update to a more recent version of Java on your Linux box. (Note that using those flags allows you to keep the more recent version of the JDK on your Windows box.)

So:

```
javac -target 1.4 -source 1.4 Foo.java Bar.java
```

Do you *have* to use GCJ rather than (say) [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/)?

Comment: could you please tell me how to do this ??

Comment: @yyyi777: Which bit? I've given you two options, and you haven't told us anything about the contraints on your Linux deployment or how you're building your code.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the version in your Linux environment, or build it with 1.4.2 on Windows.