# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: (unrecognized class file version)

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error

Hi I am facting the below exception when running in unix environment, pls any body can help

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: com.polaris.treasury.bloomberg.marketdata.test.SpringWebServiceTest (unrecognized class file version)
       at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
       at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

Comment: Sounds like your JVM is too old

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassFormatError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634768/java-lang-classformaterror)